# Return values of specific columns of documents in array of documents in MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb

I have documents stored in the following way in MongoDB:

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "arr": [
        {
            "col1": "val",
            "col2": "val"
        },
        {
            "col1": "val",
            "col2": "val"
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to query and get the following result (selecting col1 from every document in the array of every top level document) :

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "arr": [
        {
            "col1": "val"

        },
        {
            "col1": "val"

        }
    ]
}
```

How to do it in MondoDB shell?

Comment: what do you mean, sorry? What documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify what you want in your projection:

```
db.a.find({},{'arr.col2' : 0, _id : 0})
```

Comment: Thanks. It haven't worked for me, though. I get : **"error: {
        "$err" : "You cannot currently mix including and excluding fields. Conta
ct us if this is an issue.",
        "code" : 10053"**